# Render a Jbuilder template and assign the string to gon

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, jbuilder

Gon works nicely with Jbuilder. In particular, the documentation tells to use it like this

```
gon.jbuilder template: 'path/to/template.json.jbuilder'
```

This works nicely, but I would like to cache the template result so there is no need to re-render the template. Hence, I used `render_to_string`, like this:

```
gon.entities = Rails.cache.fetch('entities_json') do
  JSON.parse render_to_string(template: 'path/to/template.json.jbuilder')
end
```

The method returns the appropriate string, I have to pass it through JSON.parse, otherwise the `gon` variable stores a double-encoded JSON string. This is annoying, but I don't know how else to solve it.

Unfortunately, this invocation to `render_to_string` results in the whole HTML page being rendered as a string. The HTML is complete, the gon variables have the expected values, but out of a sudden, the page is not displayed as a HTML anymore in Chrome.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Has my answer solved your problem? Let me know if it helped. :)

Comment: @Gjaldon Looks good to me. I haven't had time to look into it. I will grant you the bounty early enough.

Comment: @Gjaldon The bounty is not wasted after the time ends, there is a grace period in which the bounty can be spent, before it is wasted or assigned automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you could now easily do fragment caching with Jbuilder. Here's an example I found in jbuilder's source:

Example:

```
json.cache! ['v1', @person], :expires_in => 10.minutes do |json|
  json.extract! @person, :name, :age
end
```

Applying this to your code, we will retain the following code in your controller:

```
gon.jbuilder template: 'path/to/template.json.jbuilder'
```

Then inside your jbuilder view, we'll do the fragment caching:

```
#path/to/template.json.jbuilder
json.cache! ['v1', @model], :expires_in => 10.minutes do |json|
  #your template.json.juilder code in here
end
```

Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with `render_to_string` changing the `content_type` for subsequent renders. See: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14173

Some possible workarounds are

- Explicitly set the `content_type` when you call render, e.g. `render content_type: text/html`
- Explicitly set the `content_type` for the response after calling `render_to_string`. This option might be preferred if you are putting `render_to_string` in a controller helper method and don't wish to require whoever is calling the helper method to be aware of the weirdness. e.g. `response.headers["Content-Type"] = request.format.to_s`